# How to retrieve a shopping list out of Face-Id?

Tags: iphone, face-id

So I write down what I'm going to buy before going to buy grocery.

Whether I am masked or need to enter my PIN, it's a pain to retrieve the list several times during a shopping trip. I usually use `Notes` for this list since it enables syncing from macOS.

I can of course disable an iPhone's PIN and Face-Id before entering the store and reenable afterwards, but this is far from a good solution.

How else might I prepare my iPhone to be able to pick it up, press the power button, and see a grocery list (while masked and without entering my PIN)?

Comment: I've always considered FaceID to be a poor idea. I have so far resisted all devices without TouchID precisely for this type of reason. My shopping list wakes by pressing the home button. Works well. I'm seriously hoping the rumours TouchID will return in the iPhone 13 are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fortunate enough to own an Apple Watch, you can simply use the Reminders app, and the same list will appear on the Reminders app on the watch, where you can also check off items as you put them in your cart. No FaceID or TouchID required.

The Apple Watch also can be configured to help unlock FaceID with a mask on as well. If you have a trusted Apple watch, FaceID will accept a partial Face scan with a trusted apple watch.

Comment: That's nice to know, but is such a puny display really amenable for a ten-item (or so) list? Jumping on the Apple Watch bandwagon merely for unlocking one's phone seems rather like overkill.

Comment: it is amenable, and quite legible. it scrolls easily. I would not say that purchasing an Apple Watch for this 'temporary' feature would be worthwhile. However, it is a feature among many others that lead to the further enjoyment and productivity of the iPhone. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reminders to do that :

- Write your shopping list in a Reminder (in notes) and give it a title
- Set a notification a few minutes before going in the shop
- You should see your shopping list on your lockscreen by long-pressing on it

Otherwise, you can screenshot the note and set it as the lockscreen wallpaper.

Comment: I think the issue is the screen going to sleep & having to be re-woken every time you need to re-check it.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15.4, which is currently in beta (https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/), supports a feature that allows unlocking while wearing a mask.

15.4 should become available to the general public in the coming months and will resolve this problem.

Comment: Very interesting. So this is not just a rumor. I have the impression that even on iOS 14 FaceID recently started to let me unlock with my eyes and nose uncovered, but with my mouth and chin masked. Eventually perhaps a signature from one's iris might suffice.